# Spring capturar error antes del controlador

Tags: java, spring

Tengo unos servicios web-rest en Spring y aceptan un body.
Si un usuario mal intencionado crea un body incorrecto:

```
{
 \"usuario": "blabla"
}
```

Spring maneja la excepción automáticamente devolviendo el error:

```
 "code": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
   "message": "JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3fb5605c; line: 2, column: 4]",
   "type": "T",
   "component": "UNKNOWN_COMPONENT",
   "application": "Mweb",
   "timeStamp": "2022-02-18T13:15:39.224Z",
   "errors": [{"code": "UNKNOWN_ERROR"}],
   "stackTrace":    [
            {
         "methodName": "readJavaType",
         "fileName": "AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java",
         "lineNumber": 240
      },
            {
         "methodName": "read",
         "fileName": "AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java",
         "lineNumber": 225
      },
            {
         "methodName": "readWithMessageConverters",
         "fileName": "AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java",
         "lineNumber": 201
      },
            {
         "methodName": "readWithMessageConverters",
         "fileName": "RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java",
         "lineNumber": 150
      },
            {
         "methodName": "resolveArgument",
         "fileName": "RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java",
         "lineNumber": 128
      }
   ]
}
```

Como la aplicación falla antes de llegar a mi controlador, cuando intenta crear el objeto de entrada, necesito devolver un mensaje "personalizado" antes.

He leído y he probado a usar:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

/**
 * Se captura el tipo de error.
 * @param e objeto capturado
 * @return salida del metodo.
 */
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public ResponseEntity<myException> handleException(Exception e){
return crearException(e,Constantes.INTERNAL_SERVER_CODE, Constantes.EXCEPTION_HANDLER_JSON);
 }

/**
 * Metodo auxiliar para crear el objeto del error
 * @param e objeto capturado
 * @return objeto del error.
 */
private ResponseEntity<myException> crearException()......
```

El problema es que no entra dentro del método.

He elegido el HttpMessageNotReadableException porque en la consola del Java es el primero cause by que aparece como error.

Comment: Está puesto: @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para manejar la excepción `HttpMessageNotReadableException` crea una clase que herede de `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` y sobrescribe el método `handleHttpMessageNotReadable` con tu respuesta personalizada. Un posible ejemplo:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(sendCustomMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    private Map<String, String> sendCustomMessage() {
        return Map.of("Error", "Entrada Errónea");
    }
}
```